# Is there a (more or less) common "real" life example for $1/x$ or $1/x^2$?

Tags: functions

I'm looking for some (more or less) common problems from "real" life related to $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$, $y=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ etc.

It's rather easy to find lineal, exponential or quadratic examples (a candle burning uniformly, bacteria growth, braking distance...), but are there any relations described with$$y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$or $y=\dfrac{c}{x^2}$, with $c\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Newtonian gravity has $F=G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}$ and similarly with Coulomb's law in electrostatics

Comment: Gravitation potential is proportional to $\frac 1r$, where $r$ is the distance. Gravitational force is proportional to $\frac 1{r^2}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{r^2}$ appears pretty frequently as it can describe how the energy of a propagating signal (e.g. sound or sunlight) is spread out since, ideally, at each moment the energy is conserved in a sphere of increasing radius.